# Triggering countUp once

Tags: jquery, html

I have been looking for a way to sort this out, in counterUp after passing in the code it works but if the window is scrolled back to top and down to the point(that's the class) it starts counting again. Are there ways to prevent this.

```js
   

$(".elevator").on("click", function() {
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
 }, 500);
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  
$(window).scroll(function () {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop())
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1460) {
    $('#elevateTop').show( "slide", {direction: "right" },500);
       
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() < 1459) {
    $('#elevateTop').hide( "slide", {direction: "right" },500);
}
});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

$('.integers').counterUp({
delay: 10,
time:   1000,
triggerOnce:true
})
});
```

```html
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <h1 style="color: #e74c3c;">
  <span class="integers">200</span>
 </h1>
```

Comment: Your code snippet runs with an error. What is `counterUp()`? What library do you use for that?

Comment: Can you shouw your full JS code? The plugin itself only runs once, mainly because document.ready is only fired once so I'm assuming it has to do with something else in your code.

Comment: It sounds like you want to be watching the window scroll event to fire this function, rather than document.ready.

Comment: its a jquery plugIn counterUp.js @semanser

Comment: I have updated my code @Jeffrey von Grumbkow

Comment: Can you try just having one document.ready